# Change font color with jscolor

Tags: jscolor

Let this piece of html code:

```
<button
   id= 'btnBckGrndColor'
   class="jscolor {valueElement:'valueInput', styleElement:'zColorSample'}">A button
</button>

 Chosen value: <input id="valueInput" value="">

 <div id="zColorSample">Some text</div>
```

Clearly it modifies the *background* color of `zColorSample`.

How do I modify the *font* color of `zColorSample`?

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I figured I would answer because I just had this issue. To achieve this using JsColor, I just added the class jscolor to the input element then added the attribute onchange, which pointed to an update function that would update the font color instead. Here is an example of what I did,

```
<input type="text" class="jscolor" onchange="update(this.jscolor);" />
<p id="toChange">Text To Change</p>
```

Then the update function looked like this using jQuery,

```
function update(jscolor) {
    $('#toChange').css("color", "#" + jscolor);}
```

Comment: Hello, Mitch: I am going to double-check this and if your solution is borne out I will thumb you up.